# Why does my Perl max() function always return the first element of the array?

Tags: perl, arrays, foreach, max

I am relatively new to Perl and I do not want to use the [List::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html) `max` function to find the maximum value of a given array.

When I test the code below, it just returns the first value of the array, not the maximum.

```
sub max
{
    my @array = shift;
    my $cur = $array[0];
    foreach $i (@array)
    {
        if($i > $cur)
        {
            $cur = $i;
        }
        else
        {
            $cur = $cur;
        }
    }
    return $cur;
   }
```

Comment: Now that you've learned how to implement max(), use List::Util's max().  It'll be faster and have less bugs.

Comment: Any particular reason why you don't want to / can't use List::Util's `max`?

Comment: Just a tip: `else { $cur = $cur }` does nothing at all, so remove it. Variables don't forget their values just because you didn't use them this time through a loop :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Replace

```
my @array = shift;
```

with

```
my @array = @_;
```

`@_` is the array containing *all* function arguments. `shift` only grabs the first function argument and removes it from @_. Change that code and it should work correctly!

Comment: This works, but would you mind explaining it? I thought you pass parameters through the shift keyword..?

Comment: Updated my post :) Btw, you should also do 'foreach my $i' (or 'for my $i', which means the same thing - for and foreach are interchangeable) to explicitly declare the $i variable in the same way you declare @array and $cur.

Comment: Subroutine parameters are passed in the `@_` array. `shift` removes the first value from the specified array and returns it - calling `shift` with no arguments causes it to act on the `@_` array.

Comment: lotsofsloths: so the two common ways of "declaring" arguments are: `my ($an_arg, $another_arg) = @_;` or `my $an_arg = shift; my $another_arg = shift;`

Comment: Inside a sub, shift with no arguments shifts from @_ (the arguments to the sub).  Outside of any sub, it shifts from @ARGV (the arguments to the script).

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you want to use something that works?

One of the ways to solve problems like this is to debug your data structures. At each step you print the data you have to see if what you expect is actually  in there. That can be as simple as:

```
 print "array is [@array]\n";
```

Or for complex data structures:

```
 use Data::Dumper;
 print Dumper( \@array );
```

In this case, you would have seen that `@array` has only one element, so there it must be the maximum.

If you want to see how list assignment and subroutine arguments work, check out [Learning Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596520113).

Comment: I assume he's trying to practice Perl programming. Haven't we all written our own sort function at some point? :)

Comment: I try not to assume. That's why I ask. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can write the function as:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

print max(@ARGV);

sub max {
    my $max = shift;
    $max >= $_ or $max = $_ for @_;
    return $max;
}
```

However, it would be far more efficient to pass it a reference to the array and even more efficient to use `List::Util::max`.